# YAML code not well formed for S3 Bucket Encryption

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here.  I am trying to enforce the S3 bucket to use the KMS key, which i am referencing, but the YAML format is incorrect.  Can you advice. Thanks

```
  TrailBucket:
    Condition: InternalBucket
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: {
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:        *********
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: !Ref Key
    }
  TrailBucketPolicy:
    Condition: InternalBucket
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref TrailBucket
      PolicyDocument:
```

If i remove the brackets {}, then i get the following error message in cloud-formation

```
The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets and asterisks

Comment: Hi, i have already tried that and i get the error message above - XML

Comment: Is `PolicyDocument` actually blank or just truncated in that snippet?